# MATLAB: Converting from for loop, to no loop

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a function provided by the instructor, which is not available for us to see the inner workings.

This function basically integrates whatever you input it.

Here is our loop:

```
for i = 1:length(time)-1
    intdefValues(i) = intdef(t, r, time(i), time(i+1));
end
```

We are trying to do this:

```
intdefValues = intdef(t, r, time(1:end-1), time(2:end));
```

Are we wrong? Is there anyway that the function doesn't support vectors?

Syntax for the function in case you are curious;

```
intdef(t, x, a, b)
```

Where t = time vector, x = function, and a,b are the start / end parameters.

Comment: when you try with no loop, does function give an error?

Comment: *Are we wrong? Is there anyway that the function doesn't support vectors?* Yes, the function may accept only scalars, not vectors, as inputs. Just to be sure, you should ask your instructor more details about the syntax of the function in question. Or as @ParagS.Chandakkar suggested, try to feed it vectors, and see if you get an error.

Comment: Also, even if you find out some way to feed vectors, that may not make the program run faster since you are changing the way the function `intdef()` works. So may not be worth investigating.

Answer (score -1):

```
tic();                               % ------------
                                     % TEST ALSO
                                     % PERFORMANCE:

                                     % prepare another "vectorOfTimeENDs",
                                     % aligned with your loop-ing strategy
                                     % for a fully  vectorised call

startsVector = time(1:end-1);        % just a syntax-sugar, may omit for speed == time(1:end-1)
  endsVector = time(2:end);          % this one is important

intdefValues = intdef( tVector, rFunction, startsVector, endsVector );
toc()

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
tic();                               % COMPARE WITH THE ORIGINAL FOR/LOOP:
for i = 1:length(time)-1
    intdefValues(i) = intdef( tVector, rFunction, time(i), time(i+1) );
end
toc()
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Jubobs Right, black-box testing ( as the OP is stating the problem to belong to ) is not a field to be able to answer your question directly. Neither we, nor the OP knows the inner details of the function implementation. Nevertheless even the black-box testing may IMHO indirectly prove a PASS/FAIL dilemma, whether the function ( alike a lot of well designed / performance tuned LIBs ) is internally designed so as to support a verctorised modus operandi, or not.